# How to define replacement rule for Minkowski inner product

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching, rule, products

following question,

I have an expression that consists of several Minkowski inner products between 2 four vectors written as in Mathematika:

`Dotp[{qm[0], qm[1], qm[2], qm[3]},{qn[0], qn[1], qn[2], qn[3]}]`,

Which I want to evaluate explicitly.

The Minkowski inner product I defined as:

`Mi = {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -1}};`

`doM = {qm[0], qm[1], qm[2], qm[3]}.Mi.{qn[0], qn[1], qn[2], qn[3]};`

`doM=qm[0] qn[0] - qm[1] qn[1] - qm[2] qn[2] - qm[3] qn[3];`

To evaluate the Minkowski inner products in the Expressions explicitly. For this I wanted to define a replacement rule that acts on

`Dotp[{qm[0], qm[1], qm[2], qm[3]},{qn[0], qn[1], qn[2], qn[3]}]`

,and gives me

`qm[0] qn[0] - qm[1] qn[1] - qm[2] qn[2] - qm[3] qn[3]`.

My current approach to define a rule:

`rule1 = {Dotp[{x1_[0], x1_[1], x1_[2], x1_[3]}, {x2_[0], x2_[1], x2_[2], x2_[3]}] :-> {x1_[0], x1_[1], x1_[2], x1_[3]}.Mi.{x2_[0], x2_[1], x2_[2], x2_[3]}}`;

But then I get the error message:

`RuleDelayed::rhs: Pattern x1_ appears on the right-hand side of rule Dotp[{x1_[0],x1_[1],x1_[2],q1_[3]},{x2_[0],x2_[1] ,x2_[2],x2_[3]}]:>{x1_[0],x1_[1],x1_[2],x1_[3]}.Mi.{x2_[0],x2_[1],x2_ [2],x2_[3]}`.

My question is, how do I define rule s.t

`Dotp[{qm[0], qm[1], qm[2], qm[3]},{qn[0], qn[1], qn [2], qn[3]}:->  qm[0] qn[0] - qm[1] qn[1] - qm[2] qn[2] - qm[3] qn[3]` ?

Is a rule even the right approach?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Incorrect: `{x_ :> x_^2}`. Correct: `{x_ :> x^2}`.

Answer (score 7):

```
Mi = DiagonalMatrix[{1,-1,-1,-1}]

Dotp[{qm[0], qm[1], qm[2], qm[3]}, {qn[0], qn[1], qn[2], qn[3]}] /.  Dotp[t1_List, t2_List] :> (t1.Mi.t2)
```

Or

```
Block[
   {
      Dotp= Function[{t1, t2},(t1.Mi.t2)]
   },
   Dotp[{qm[0], qm[1], qm[2], qm[3]}, {qn[0], qn[1], qn[2], qn[3]}]
]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Dotp[{qm[0], qm[1], qm[2], qm[3]}, {qn[0], qn[1], qn[2], qn[3]}] /. 
 Dotp[a_List, b_List] :> Fold[#1 - #2 &, a b]
```

> qm[0] qn[0] - qm[1] qn[1] - qm[2] qn[2] - qm[3] qn[3]

Comment: Your `Fold[#1-#2&,a b]` is an amusing trick, but probably difficult to understand for people that are new to Mathematica.

Comment: @user293787 I remember a time when it was not even on my radar.

Comment: why does the ``Fold[#1 - #2 &, a b]`` term have the same function as (t1 . Mi . t2) ?

Comment: Focus on the first term `#1` and the second term `#2` of the element-wise product `a b`. Do a `#1-#2&`, you get: `qm[0] qn[0] - qm[1] qn[1]`. Now this becomes the first term. The second term is the next one in the list. When it `folds`, you get `qm[0] qn[0]` - `qm[1] qn[1] - qm[2] qn[2]`; and so it goes until the end of the list. You can study more examples from the docs. Change `Fold` to `FoldList` to see the steps.